# jqGrid Json,decompression

Tags: jqgrid

Use jqGrid, how to load the local json request directly data without url, consult ace,

JqGrid whether uncompressed version of the source

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean under "decompression" or "uncompressed". If you want use not minimized version of jqGrid you should just include [another JavaScript files](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ahow_to_install#development_installation).

If the data are a string in JSON format you should create the grid using the parameter `datastr` and the `datatype:'jsonstring'` (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_string) for more information). If the data are not JSON but an object instead you can use [data](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) parameter and `datatype:'local'` or methods like [setRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods). Take in the consideration that the usage of `localReader` can be required (see [Array Data](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#array_data) in the documentation).